# How to create live tracking in react native?

Tags: react-native, google-maps, geolocation, maps, tracking

Can anyone tell me please , how to create live tracking in react native ? Using geolocation ,react native maps or other dependencies, i wanna make a tracking driver like uber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you have installed react-native-maps and added the necessary packages to your application. Use the below given code in **componentDidMount()**. The below given code will be called whenever your location will be changed. and it will provide you the updated location. Here you will also find the heading, you can use heading to show the vehicle direction or alignment.

```
this.watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
  (position) => {
    this.locationPermission = true;
    console.log('Watch Position response', position);
    const { coordinate } = this.state;
    const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords;
    const newCoordinate = {
      latitude,
      longitude
    };
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      if (this.marker) { this.marker._component.animateMarkerToCoordinate(newCoordinate, 500); }
    }
    else {
      coordinate.timing(newCoordinate).start();
    }

    this.setState({
      marker: {
        latlng: {
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
        }
      },
      heading: position.coords.heading,
    })


    );

  },
  (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
  { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000, distanceFilter: 10 },
);
```

Comment: Once you start the tracking, does the map rotate to follow using direction according to the directions line  ? like Google Maps live route

Comment: It will not @MUSTAPHAGHLISSI, You can use heading to get the direction and rotate the map accordingly.

Comment: Can give a reference or any  help link please ?

Comment: Hey, can you explain what is "navigator" in your code? I've seen examples of this piece of code but this variable is never imported or created

Comment: @Kailash it is slow though, rendering the marker view for the current user locaiton is so slow when user is moving. Any solution for this problem?