# GPS location fluctuating in react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am using GPS location in one of my app in react native. I need to track user location at some intervals. but I am getting different latitude and longitude. I have already set it for high accuracy. But it does not return the accurate location of the user. Also, I found GPS return different locations in IOS and Android. Please help me with how I can get exact location of the user.

Comment: It might be a solution for you.
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60175773/how-to-create-live-tracking-in-react-native/60279363#60279363

Answer (score 4):

I am facing this problem a while ago, this core geolocation api doesn't work perfectly on real devices even you using the HighAccuracy flag true, so here i have found some lib which you can use in order to get exact location

[react-native-geolocation-service](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-geolocation-service)

Here is my code which I have used with above lib, have tested with both IOS and android Devices

```
import Geolocation from 'react-native-geolocation-service'
```

This function used to get current location of use

```
const getUserCorrectLocation = async () => {
await Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  currentLocation => {
    const { coords } = currentLocation

  },
  error => {
    console.log(error, 'error')
  },
  { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 15000, maximumAge: 10000, distanceFilter: 0, 
  forceRequestLocation: true }
)}
```

Second function that I have used is to track user location when he
start his journey

```
useEffect(() => {
  const watchId = Geolocation.watchPosition(
    position => {
      const { coords } = position

    },
    error => {
      console.log(error, 'coords')
    },
    {
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      interval: 2000,
      fastestInterval: 1000,
      distanceFilter: 2
    }
  )
  return () => Geolocation.clearWatch(watchId)
}},[])
```

Comment: I've spent really lots of time trying to define how to properly use options and your answer solved my issue.